# Как сравнивать 3 элементы в if else?

Tags: javascript

Я хочу написать функцию, которая будет сравнивать 3 элемента: если `A = B = C`, то выполнить какую-то функцию.

То есть мне нужно, чтобы функция выполнилась только тогда, когда 3 элемента равны друг другу.

Подскажите пожалуйста, как это реализовать?

Мой код прикрепляю ниже:

```js
if (img1.src == img2.src == img3.src) {
            winner.style.display = 'block';
            winner.innerHTML = 'You Win';
        } else {
            winner.style.display = 'block';
            winner.innerHTML = 'You Lose';
        }
```

```html
img3
```

Comment: Ваш код не работает по следующей причине: оператор сравнения `==` между двумя операндами возвращает значение `1`, если операнды равны, `0`, если операнды не равны. То есть вы сравниваете `1` или `0` с `img3.src`.

Таким образом: `1 == 1 == 1` вернёт `true`, но `2 == 2 == 2` вернёт `false`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If(img1 == img2 && img2 == img3)

Answer (score 4):

```js
let a = 1
let b = 1
let d = 1

if (a == b &&  b == d) {
document.getElementById('winner').style.display = 'block';
document.getElementById('winner').innerHTML = 'You Win';
        } else {
document.getElementById('winner').style.display = 'block';
document.getElementById('winner').innerHTML = 'You Lose';
        }
```

```html
<div id="winner"></div>
```

```js
let a = 1
let b = 2
let d = 1

if (a == b &&  b == d) {
document.getElementById('winner').style.display = 'block';
document.getElementById('winner').innerHTML = 'You Win';
        } else {
document.getElementById('winner').style.display = 'block';
document.getElementById('winner').innerHTML = 'You Lose';
        }
```

```html
<div id="winner"></div>
```